# List all Sources and Sinks in a Flink SQL job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-table-api

I'm building a sort of wrapper around Flink SQL. I construct a job with a bunch of user-specified SQL statements with `StreamTableEnvironment.sqlUpdate`. Some are `INSERT`s, some are `CREATE`s. I also do some `sqlQuery`s.

Before I'm calling `StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute`, I'd like to list all Sources and Sinks that the user created.

Is there a simple / official way to do it, or do I need to go exploring with `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph().getJobGraph().getVerticesSortedTopologicallyFromSources()`?

Best regards

EDIT: I need the table names, and associated schemas.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, you can query tables in the `StreamTableEnvironment` with `StreamTableEnvironment.listTables()` and then do a `StreamTableEnvironment.from(tableName).getSchema()`